# "Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted." when adding claims manually

Tags: abp

I'm unable to make authorization policies works with the event OnTokenValidated of AddJwtBearer, I try to set the claims to the user as the [PasswordlessAuthentication](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/PasswordlessAuthentication) sample does. I already have valid token and i'm trying to save the user if not exists and add a role with corresponding permissions. But I always get the error from the endpoints "Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted. [ApplicationName].Category". What else can we do?

This is my ConfigureAuthentication() looks like, the configure middleware is unchanged from the template.

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.AddAuthentication()                
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/zzzz";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/zzzz",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "zzzz",
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                };
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IdentityUserManager>();
                        var email = context.Principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == AbpClaimTypes.Email).FirstOrDefault().Value;
                        IdentityUser user = await userService.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            user = new IdentityUser(Guid.NewGuid(), email, email);
                            await userService.CreateAsync(user);
                        }

                        await userService.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);

                        var roles = await userService.GetRolesAsync(user);

                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                            new Claim("sub", user.Id.ToString()),
                            new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.UserId, user.Id.ToString()),
                            new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                            new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.UserName, user.UserName),
                            new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.EmailVerified, user.EmailConfirmed.ToString().ToLower()),
                            };

                        foreach (var role in roles)
                        {
                            claims.Add(new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.Role, role));
                        }

                        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme));

                        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
                    }
                };
            });
    }
```

Comment: You can add something like this https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/ to attach the  new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.Role, "admin") in the OnTokenValidated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no time to go through your particular example but maybe I can give you an idea where to look at.
The exception is thrown in 'Volo.Abp.Authorization' project
[image]

it's related to the abp.io [permission system](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization)

in short, that's how you add it (policy names are created here)

```
   /*
    A permission is a simple policy that is granted or prohibited for a particular user, role or client.
    ABP automatically discovers this class. No additional configuration required!
*/
public class TestPermissionDefinitionProvider : PermissionDefinitionProvider
{
    public override void Define(IPermissionDefinitionContext context)
    {
        var myGroup = context.AddGroup("Test", L("Permission:Test"));
        myGroup.AddPermission("Test.Products", L("Permission:ProductManagement"));
        //...
    }
```

and that's how you use it in your Application service
[image]

So, if the current user doesn't have the policy, you will get the exception.
Usually the policies are set to roles, so when you create a new user you assign a role to it (say 'admin').
You can check if a particular role has a given policy both through the web interface and in the database (table 'AbpPermissionGrants')